# Mocking functions with cmocka

Tags: unit-testing, embedded, cmocka

I'm trying to mock some functions using cmocka:

```
void test_led_driver_NeedToImplement(void **state)
{
       
    state_t current = CLEAR;
    will_return(led_status_toggel,SET);
    
    TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(SET, led_status_toggel(current));
}
```

But, I get an error:  led_status_toggel() has remaining non-returned values.
Do I have to create a mock file for my functions or what's the source of this error?
Ps: I'm using unity.h as an assertions library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your test, it seams that function you are testing is `led_status_toggel`. If that is the case, you should not mock it. You should just remove `will_return(led_status_toggel,SET);`, since your `led_status_toggel` is probably something like this (You dind't share it so I don't know exactly):

```
state_t led_status_toggel(state_t state)
{
    if (state == CLEAR)
    {
        return SET;
    }       
    return CLEAR;
}
```

If your function under test is not `led_status_toggel`, but some other (that you didn't mentioned) which calls this `led_status_toggel`, then you can mock this function like this

```
state_t __wrap_led_status_toggel(state_t state)
{
    return (state_t)mock();
}
```

and use `-Wl,--wrap=led_status_toggel` in your build command. With `--wrap` linker flag, when you execute your test, the mock function `__wrap_led_status_toggel` will be called instead of the original `led_status_toggel`.